# Añadir recuento de ips a mi servidor local

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, script

Quiero tener un recuento de las ips que se conectan a mi pagina web(local). Es decir, si se conecta una persona, que me muestre 1, si hay 2, pues 2 y así sucesivamente. La idea del proyecto es no usar bases de datos sino almacenar los datos en una lista.

```
//Detectar cuando se conecta un cliente
    let ips= []
    let user_ip= socket.handshake.address
    if(ips.includes(user_ip)){
        console.log("if")
        console.log(ips.length)
        console.log(ips)
    }else{
        ips.push(user_ip)
        console.log("else")
        console.log(ips.length)
        console.log(ips)
    }
```

Comment: Echale un ojo a esto https://hdtuto.com/article/node-js-get-real-time-online-users-counter-using-socket-io-example ;)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses [socket.lo](https://socket.io) para que tu contador sea en tiempo real y sin necesidad de usar base de datos.

Para eso vas a necesitar instalarlo de este modo

```sh
npm i socket.io
```

Y tomando en cuenta el ejemplo de código que mostré en el enlace, y mejorándolo un poco para que funcioné correctamente

Back-end:

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8001);

const count = 0;
const $ipsConnected = [];
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  let $ipAddress = socket.handshake.address;
  if (!$ipsConnected.find(u => u.ip === $ipAddress)) {
    // sino existe la ip la agregamos
    $ipsConnected.push({
      ip: $ipAddress
    });
    count++; // aumentamos el contador por cada ip
    socket.emit('counter', { count: count });
  }
  console.log("client is connected");
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    $ipsConnected = $ipsConnected.find(u => u.ip !== $ipAddress); // solo quitamos la ip que coincida con la ip del usuario que se haya desconectado
    count--; // disminuimos el contador
    socket.emit('counter', { count:count });
  });
});
```

Front-end:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Node JS - Get Real time online users counter using socket io example</title>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Conter : <span id="counter"></span></h1>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('counter', function (data) {
    $("#counter").text(data.count);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Me disculpó por la tardanza pero tenia cosas que hacer

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme, funciona casi todo! Pero a la hora de establecer el find a el array, me dice que $ipsConnected no es una funcion. Me tira el siguiente error.                                                                                               $ipsConnected.find is not a function

Comment: Que raro!! Yo hice un test y funciona perfectamente sin errores